# Changed PATH variable and now Terminal won't accept most console commands

Tags: macos, command-line, path, console, terminal

I'm a newbie to programming, and I've recently started learning basic Terminal commands on my Mac OSX 10.8. One exercise involved changing the PATH variable by entering this into the console:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

After the Text editor opened, the tutorial prompted me to change the PATH by entering this line at the bottom of the file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Users/myuser/desktop:$PATH"
```

Where "myuser" is my computer's username.

I did so, and now the Terminal won't accept most commands I attempt to input - e.g. cd, ls, clear, raising the error:

```
-bash: clear: command not found
```

I've tried using the touch command as well to get back into the bash_profile, but that won't work either. When I echo the PATH, I get this output:

```
/Users/myuser/Users/myuser/desktop:#PATH
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put in `#PATH` instead of `$PATH`.

You'll have to edit `~/.bash_profile` to fix that. To open it, open a terminal and enter:

```
$ /usr/bin/open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then edit it to use `$PATH` instead of `#PATH`, save, and open a new terminal; your `$PATH` should work again.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

mipadi is right #PATH has to be change by $PATH but your command is still not correct :

export PATH="$HOME/Users/myuser/desktop:$PATH"
$HOME value is "/Users/myuser", so this is equivalent to  PATH="/Users/myuser/Users/myuser/desktop:$PATH"

You have to choose go for ONE of those lines (they are all the same) :

```
export PATH="$HOME/Desktop:$PATH"
export PATH="~/Desktop:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/myuser/Desktop:$PATH"
```

Note the capital D at "Desktop", this is case-sensitive.
I do not want to question you, but adding the ~/Desktop as part of the environment variables is not common (likely not a good practice).

Regards,
Florian